# Facebook "Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later" - Ionic

Tags: android, firebase, facebook, ionic-framework

Trying to implement Facebook login in my Ionic app i'm stuck on this error, after distribution on Play Store, at the moment of login:

> Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uihq5.jpg)

Scenario:

- Ionic 5
- cordova-plugin-facebook4 v5.13.0
- `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />`

If I try to do the same thing with the app builded and selfsigned on my PC it works properly. The problem occurs after the distribution on Play Store, with the app downloaded from it.

I've added to Facebook Developer Console all required hash keys: the hash key of my self signed certificate and the Google Play one, but it's not working.

Someone has some ideas?

**Solution**: Removed `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />`

Answer (score 0):

For those came to this question by this error, when loggin in from web app: there can be different problem: if you are not administrator of the app you get this. But if adminitrator does login, he gets more accurate error, by which he can see that "Client OAuth Login" is not enabled, maybe same would be for android.